# opencart blank admin module page

Tags: module, opencart

I working with opencart Version 2.0.3.0 well the site was working perfectly. But suddenly in admin panel module page shows a blank page.

I've enabled the display errors. But it seems that this problem is not based on the listed errors.

Using the backup file replaced the file in admin/controller/extension/module.php but which is not solving the issue.

This is what I'm getting after displaying the errors.

Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/logs/error.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/library/log.php on line 6

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/library/log.php on line 10

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/library/log.php on line 10

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/library/log.php on line 10

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/system/library/log.php on line 10

and I think this is not the issue, These errors were there before this issue.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Well why haven't you posted the error messages you're getting and we can decide if they are the problem or not?

Comment: check error log in this path system/logs/error.log  i think this will help you.

Comment: @PaulFeakins i've edited the question n added the errors

Comment: are you using linux

Comment: @Prashant This was i found while checking the error log 

2017-11-07 10:11:13 - PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Permission denied. in /var/www/html/xxxxx.xx/admin/controller/extension/installer.php on line 345

Comment: @RahulShrivastava yes Linux ubuntu

Comment: chmod -R 777 /www   try to run in terminal

Comment: @RahulShrivastava I just set the recursive permission. now the errors are not displaying. but the module page still shows a blank page

Comment: can you share your website details with me ?

Comment: Don't put 777 on files. That is a potential security threat.